# Woocommerce data in the plugin to work with track codes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to retrieve total order price at thank you page but unable to figure out why `$order->order_total();` not working.

Facebook has its own plugin when using the pixel, they give you to download it and then install on wordpress, to improve tracking I need to install a small code on the thank you page of woocommerce, the code requires total order amount in order to track the transaction properly, So what I am doing is trying to change this code,

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '0.00', currency:'PKR'});
```

into this

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '<?php $order->order_total', currency:'PKR'});
```

tried all the variations

```
$order->order_total()
$order->order_total();
```

but eventually got to know that somehow I was not able to retrieve the order total amount, So I tried to past this into header of my theme.

Now my question is the way Thank you page is showing my total amount, I just want to re-use it how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If the $order doesn't exist in the context you are trying to use it then you'll have a problem.  Check your debug.log file for errors to see if this is the case.  How are you using this Facebook pixel code with WooCommerce?